# How can i delete double quote in bash file.(Linux)

Tags: linux, bash, double-quotes

```
for i in $(some function); do somefunction2 $i; done

-su: 0 5 : syntax error in expression (error token is "5 ")
```

My problem is some function return "0 9" I can't use this:

```
for i in "0 5"; do somefunction2 $i; done
```

Results are the same

```
-su: 0 5 : syntax error in expression (error token is "5 ")
```

but if use this:

```
for i in 0 5; do somefunction2 $i; done
```

It works. Some function for loop and echo this

```
echo -n "$i "
```

I want return `0 5` not `"0 5"` How can I do?

Comment: as a quick fix , $(some function | tr -d "\"")

Comment: you need to post the *real* code because you are telling us that you think the problem is with bash and quotes (a quite fantastic conclusion IMHO). That cannot be true as the error is rise by the "su" command which I cannot see anywhere in your question. Basically I believe that your problem is with somefunction2 and the syntax used to call "su" but we cannot help with the info you provide.

Comment: at this moment with the info you've provided in your question I just can only do guesses about your problem. I can reproduce a similar error if I do: `echo "$[ 0 5 ]"` which yields: `bash: 0 5 : syntax error in expression (error token is "5 ")` which is obviously caused by a wrong arithmetic expansion. **Recheck the syntax** in your code.

Comment: I could not understand what is exactly being asked here .. ???? Please post your real code

Answer (score 0):

This should solve your problem:

```
eval for i in $(some function); do somefunction2 \$i; done
```

However, it's not clear from your question where does the `su` come from ?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to delete anything:

```
   function five {
   echo 0;
   echo 5;
   }

   function fiveString {
   echo "0 5";
   }

   for i in `five`;do
   echo process $i;
   done

   for i in $(echo $(fiveString));do
   echo process $i;
   done
```